# How is a Yubikey static password derived from the AES key?

Tags: key-derivation

When I configure a Yubikey slot as static, it's not documented or obvious how the static password yielded by a press relates to the AES key I set.  For example:

```
me@mine:~$ ykpersonalize -1 -ostatic-ticket -ofixed=cccccccccccc -a00000000000000000000000000000000             
Firmware version 2.3.3 Touch level 1795 Program sequence 9

Configuration data to be written to key configuration 1:

fixed: m:cccccccccccc
uid: 000000000000
key: h:00000000000000000000000000000000
acc_code: h:000000000000
ticket_flags: APPEND_CR
config_flags: STATIC_TICKET
extended_flags: 

Commit? (y/n) [n]: y

me@mine:~$ cat >/dev/null  # and do a short press...
ccccccccccccncejelrjvjvvciclerknrlihnteljrcb
```

Where does the key-based part (`ncejelrjvjvvciclerknrlihnteljrcb`) come from?

Answer (score 1):

The password is the result of encrypting the fields used for OTP, but with fixed values:

```
me@mine:~$ ykparse 00000000000000000000000000000000 ncejelrjvjvvciclerknrlihnteljrcb
Input:
  token: ncejelrjvjvvciclerknrlihnteljrcb
          b0 38 3a c8 f8 ff 07 0a 3c 9b ca 76 bd 3a 8c 01 
  aeskey: 00000000000000000000000000000000
          00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Output:
          00 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 0f 2e 

Struct:
  uid: 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  counter: 65535 (0xffff)
  timestamp (low): 65535 (0xffff)
  timestamp (high): 255 (0xff)
  session use: 255 (0xff)
  random: 65535 (0xffff)
  crc: 11791 (0x2e0f)

Derived:
  cleaned counter: 32767 (0x7fff)
  modhex uid: cccccccccccc
  triggered by caps lock: yes
  crc: F0B8
  crc check: ok
```

This can be reproduced with OpenSSL:

```
me@mine:~$ key=00000000000000000000000000000000
me@mine:~$ fixed='\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x0f\x2e'
me@mine:~$ modhex -h $(echo -ne "$fixed" | openssl enc -aes128 -nopad -K $key -iv "" \
                       | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x"')
ncejelrjvjvvciclerknrlihnteljrcb
```

You can't quite reproduce it with `ykgenerate` because that tool always includes a genuinely unpredictable `random:` field.